# Removing Windows 10 Packages with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new here, so I apologize in advance for any imprecision. I recently had to format my pc and reinstall Windows 10 pro (version 21H2). Since Windows comes with packages I don't want, I decided to get rid of them via Powershell. Once I accessed Powershell as Admin, I've looked what packages were installed with  "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers".

I've tried removing some of the unwanted ones with "Get-AppxPackage PackageFullName | Remove-AppxPackage" with no success (since I've notice that using "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers" again, the packages I've tried to remove were still there).

In this second try, I tried using "remove-appxpackage -AllUsers -Package PackageFullName" (I'm the only user in this pc, however I prefer to remove the packages for all the users). The last command however spawned error 0x80070002, which googling its source, can be caused by multimple things.

Am I doing this wrong? Maybe I'm using wrong commands? How can I solve this problem and go ahead removing unwanted packages? Thanks in advance for your patience and help!

Comment: Hello Vomit, if for command elevated as admin you mean "right click, run as administrator", then yes.

Comment: Can you be more specific of which packages your trying to remove?

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I'm trying to remove everything related to Xbox (I believe there are 5 packages related to Xbox), Microsoft Maps, Microsoft Wallet, Microsoft People, Microsoft Office Hub...and few more.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the exact package names you are trying to remove.

Comment: Look in to `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage`. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/remove-appxprovisionedpackage?view=windowsserver2022-ps. You remove the app from your user account like you stated and remove it from the image using this command. And some packages cannot be removed.